# Strange lines on UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

---

I have no idea why this is happening.

So this is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [thumbnails count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CamilleSeaman.jpg"];

    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 2;
}
```

---

After  removing the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method

[image]

Comment: Why are you returning 2 in heightForRow? Surely you don't want a 2 point high cell. How big is your thumbnailImageView in the xib? Is your cell type set to custom?

Comment: How do you find out how high it is? Yes it is set to custom!

Comment: why are you using Nib instead of a storyboard? And why do u load it in this ancient way instead of using the iOS4+ UINib class? did you check that really a UITableViewCell is loaded?

Comment: i just followed this http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: @Maximilian, you made the image view, don't you know how big you made it? You can look in the size inspector for its size 
(or at its constraints if you're using those).

Comment: that tutorial must had been outdated by the time it was written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

Comment: OK, it looks like your intention is to display thumbnails, so you should probably replace the cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CamilleSeaman.jpg"]; with the appropriate code (for example, cell.thumbnailImageView.image = thumbnail[indexPath.row];) as well as adding back the heightForRowAtIndexPath method with the correct height if you're not using standard height cells.

Comment: Well.. open your nib file named SimpleTableCell.xib and take a look at the height of the top view. Unless you're using AutoLayout which I somehow doubt.